# C# upload IList<IFormFILe> to one azure blob

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-blob-storage

I want to upload a List of `IFormFILe` after I change them to Stream list file could be in one upload ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I am using to upload file in Azure Blob:

```
public interface IFileStorageService
{
    Task<string> UploadImageAsync(IFormFile imageFile);
    Task<string> UploadVideoAsync(IFormFile videoFile);
}

public class FileStorageService : IFileStorageService
{
    private readonly Uri _baseUri = new Uri("YourBlobUrl");
    private readonly CloudBlobClient _client;

    public FileStorageService()
    {
        _client = new CloudBlobClient(_baseUri, new StorageCredentials("accoutName", "YourSecretKey"));
    }

    public async Task<string> UploadImageAsync(IFormFile imageFile)
    {
        try
        {
            StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(imageFile.OpenReadStream());
            var container = _client.GetContainerReference("images");
            var blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(imageFile.FileName +".jpg");
            await blob.UploadFromStreamAsync(streamReader.BaseStream);

            return new Uri(_baseUri, $"/images/{imageFile.FileName}.jpg").ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            throw;
        }

    }

    public async Task<string> UploadVideoAsync(IFormFile videoFile)
    {
        try
        {
            StreamReader videoStream = new StreamReader(videoFile.OpenReadStream());
            var container = _client.GetContainerReference("videos");
            var blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(videoFile.FileName+".mp4");
            await blob.UploadFromStreamAsync(videoStream.BaseStream);

            return new Uri(_baseUri, $"/videos/{videoFile.FileName}.mp4").ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            throw;
        }

    }
}
```

Now you can use this to upload List of `IFormFile` by just iterating through List of `IFormFile`.